# Does MySQL have query queues and what's behind query_time in the slow log?

Tags: mysql, queue, execution-time, mysql-slow-query-log

what timestamps are used for calculating the query_time parameter in the mysql slow query log? Can't find any definition of that parameter.
Only thing i found is

> The time to acquire the initial locks is not counted as execution time.

from: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html

I'm asking this question because i want to know if the time, given by the 'request_time' in slow log, includes waiting times in queues (if there are some).

**If there are some queues**, is there a possibility to log the current waiting queue length when a new query is going to be executed (preferably in the slow log).

**If there are no queues**, how does mysql handle incoming queries if all threads are currently executing some query?
Update: Remain those queries in the TCP-Buffer till they can be executed by a thread?

Links to further reading are welcome.

Regards
Korbinian

Comment: [Profile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html) the query to get the specific times, including waiting for locks.

Comment: I can not see that profiling shows how long a query has to wait in some queue (if there is any). I'm running some analysis on the such logfiles so i want to know what time the parameter exaclty shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no queues like you describe.

When the query starts, the connection is dedicated to running it.  It may be blocked by any of a large number of "mutexes" because of various things shared between connections.  As the query runs, it may have to wait for I/O to read blocks from disk.

The query time in the slowlog is essentially the clock-on-the-wall time for the query.  A query that normally takes 1 second may take 3 seconds if there are other connections hanging onto mutexes or doing lots of I/O.

Caching will let a query run faster.  The first time you run a query (after restarting mysql), it will run slow because of all the uncached I/O.

If you are using Engine MyISAM, the "lock_time" will often be significant because of MyISAM's table locking.  InnoDB rarely shows more than a fraction of a millisecond in lock_time.

In older version of MySQL, the timer was similar to TIMESTAMP with a 1-second resolution.  In newer versions, it has much higher resolution.

The time at the start of a slowlog entry is the timestamp of when the query started.  You may notice that the slowlog entries are not always in order according to that.  This is simply because a slowlog entry is not written to the file until the query finishes.

OK, there is a queue -- but it is almost never needed.  And it is at the time of establishing the connection.  If there are already `max_connection` connections, then see `back_log`.  I repeat, that is not a queue for *executing* queries.